# $A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ positive stable if and only if $\textrm{trace}(A) > 0$ and $\det(A) > 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems, machine-learning

Why is a real-valued matrix say $A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ "positive stable", if and only if $\textrm{trace}(A) > 0$ and $\det(A) > 0$?

Thank you so much

Comment: What is a positive stable matrix?

Comment: My understanding of positive stable matrix: all of its eigen values have got positive real part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both eigenvalues of $A$ are real, the trace and the determinant are both positive if and only if both eigenvalues are positive.

If the eigenvalues of $A$ are non-real, they must form a conjugate pair. and $\det(A)$ is automatically positive. Since the trace of $A$ is the double of the real parts of either eigenvalue, the conclusion follows.